# canvas.js placed different title on each datapoint set

Tags: javascript, canvas

i am creating multiple datapoints array in  canvas.js function,after chart property i applied title property,but for each data points i am getting the same title,but i want different title on different data points,how it is possible?

```
  init();
    function init() { 
      var  el=document.getElementById('chart');
      var map = L.map( 'map', {
        center: [20.5937,78.9629],
        minZoom: 2,
        zoom: 4
    });
    L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

        subdomains: ['a','b','c']
    }).addTo( map );




     var mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:7770/geoserver/cite/wms", {
        layers: 'cite:state1',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true

    });
    mywms.addTo(map);
          data=[
        [
                  { x: 1999, y : 1838.21, color: "#ccccff"},
                  { x: 2000, y : 2148.01,color: "#b2b2ff" },
                  { x: 2001, y : 2537.06,color: "#9999ff" },
                  { x: 2002, y : 2089.29 ,color: "#7f7fff"},
                  { x: 2003, y : 3276.78 ,color: "#6666ff"},
                  { x: 2004, y : 2544.60,color: "#4c4cff"},
                  { x: 2005, y : 2676.42 ,color: "#3232ff"}
        ],

          [
                  { x: 1999, y : 1475.22, color: "#ccccff"},
                  { x: 2000, y : 1354.99,color: "#b2b2ff" },
                  { x: 2001, y : 1861.67,color: "#9999ff" },
                  { x: 2002, y : 1427.08 ,color: "#7f7fff"},
                  { x: 2003, y : 1717.2 ,color: "#6666ff"},
                  { x: 2004, y : 1676.91,color: "#4c4cff"},
                  { x: 2005, y : 1900.02 ,color: "#3232ff"}
        ],


        [
                  { x: 1999, y : 2645.43, color: "#ccccff"},
                  { x: 2000, y : 2649.38,color: "#b2b2ff" },
                  { x: 2001, y : 2883.1,color: "#9999ff" },
                  { x: 2002, y : 2689.88 ,color: "#7f7fff"},
                  { x: 2003, y : 3332.6 ,color: "#6666ff"},
                  { x: 2004, y :3473.52,color: "#4c4cff"},
                  { x: 2005, y : 3721.04 ,color: "#3232ff"}
        ] 



     ],
          loc=[


            [25.7532,71.4181],


            [24.7467,72.8043],

            [27.6094,75.1399],

            [25.7711, 73.3234],

            [27.1854,74.0300],

            [28.1289,75.3995],

            [28.3254,74.4057],

            [29.9038,73.8772],

            [29.1547,74.4995],

            [26.9157,70.9083],

            [25.1257,72.1416],

            [26.28, 73.02],

            [28.0229,73.3119],
     ];

      for(var i=0;i<loc.length;i++){
        var marker=L.marker(loc[i]).addTo(map).bindPopup(el),
            options={index:i,marker:marker};
        marker.on('click', onMarkerClick, options);//'options' object will be assigned to 'this' object, when click event occures

 marker.on('mouseover', function(a) {

    //open popup;
      var popup = L.popup()
       .setLatLng(a.loc) 
       .setContent('District:')
       .openOn(map);

    });

     }  

      function onMarkerClick(e) {   
        //'this' object will be having 'options' object
        var index=this.index,
            marker=this.marker;   
         $('#chart').css('display', 'block');
         var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(el, {
            title:{
                text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
            },

        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        zoomEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        animationDuration: 4000,

          axisY:{
           title:"GDP (in Rs. Cr.)",
          valueFormatString:"#####.00",
          lineColor: "black",
          labelFontSize: 15,
               labelFontColor: "red",
               titleFontColor: "black", 
           },
          axisX:{
                title:"Year",
               valueFormatString:"####",
               labelFontSize: 15,
               labelFontColor: "red",
               lineColor: "black",
               titleFontColor: "black",
               titleFontSize: 20,
            },
            data: [              
            {
                type: "column",
                xValueFormatString:"Year ####",
            dataPoints:data[index]             
            }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();    
        marker.openPopup();    

      }
    }
```

Comment: one that come on top like i am displaying different content through each data set so i want to set different title to each dataset,understand what i want??

Comment: and whats the same title that are you getting?

Comment: title:{
                text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
            },

Comment: Are you looking for indexLabel (http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/indexlabel/)?

Comment: no index label is different thing,i am looking for individual title on my each datapoint set.